# MS SQL Выборка из нескольких таблиц по нескольким связанным полям

Tags: sql, sql-server, процедуры

У меня есть 3 таблице. 
первая - tab1

1. ИД - первичный ключ
2. ИМЯ - стринг

вторая - tab2

1. tab1ИД
2. Дни - int

третья - tab3

1. tab1ИД
2. Дата - datatime

связи между таблицами
tab1.ИД один - многие tab2.tab1ИД
tab1.ИД один - многие tab3.tab1ИД

как сделать запрос на Transaqt SQL (MS SQL 2012)?:
мне надо выбрать элементы из tab1, с условием, что если tab1.ИД = tab2.tab1ИД = tab3.tab1ИД и MAX(tab2.Дни) > (MAX(tab3.Дата) - MIN(tab3.Дата))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> мне надо выбрать элементы из tab1, с условием, что если tab1.ИД = tab2.tab1ИД = tab3.tab1ИД и MAX(tab2.Дни) > (MAX(tab3.Дата) - MIN(tab3.Дата))

Да так и сделать... практически просто перевести на аглицкий, добавить недостающие слова из объяснения выше и причесать в соответствии с требованиями синтаксиса.

```
Выбрать ИД и ИМЯ
из tab1, tab2, tab3
где tab1.ИД = tab2.tab1ИД 
  и tab1.ИД = tab3.tab1ИД
чтобы в группе по tab1
выполнялось MAX(tab2.Дни) > (MAX(tab3.Дата) - MIN(tab3.Дата))
```

Ну и после перевода

```
SELECT tab1.ID, tab1.Name
FROM tab1, tab2, tab3
WHERE tab1.id = tab2.tab1ID
  AND tab1.id = tab3.tab1ID
GROUP BY tab1.ID, tab1.Name
HAVING MAX(tab2.Days) > DATEDIFF(day, MIN(tab3.Date), (MAX(tab3.Date))
```

Поскольку tab3.Date имеет тип Datetime и может содержать компоненту времени, может понадобиться перед расчётом разности округлить значения до дней. А может и не понадобиться.

Comment: Так не работает, выдает ошибку "Column 'tab1.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Значит, Вы допустили ошибку при копировании или модификации кода. В моём коде поле tab1.ID явно присутствует в выражении группировки.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо